# Maps for WinPhone 8 -- how to detect when you're offroad

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I want to develop a Windows Phone 8 app, that records the path traveled, when the user has went off the road that's marked on the map. I want to use Bing maps for this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207045(v=vs.105).aspx).

For as far as my google-foo tells me, there's no specific way of asking the API if the user's location is "on-road" or "off-road". Am i wrong?

If i'm right, and there's no built in functionality for this, how should i go about writing an algorithm capable of detecting this?

Maybe there are other map API's that are compatible with Windows Phone 8, that are capable of this and would work in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could periodically retrieve the current position and compare it with the coordinates in your `Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Services.Route` (property `Geometry`).

If the current position diverges too much form those coordinates in the `Geometry` property, then you could consider the user being off-track. It's up to you to find a boundary value.